# How to use the repeat in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this program and i need to use the (repeat -1) if the number is invalid:

```
number = input('value:')
def validateNumber(number): 
    while True:
        if number.isdigit() and (len(number) == 10):
            break

        elif (len(number) != 10):
            print('invalid input')
            return -1
validateNumber(number)
```

It will come out like this:

```
value:123
invalid input
```

I want to make it continue to loop until there is 10 digit value is entered:

```
value:123
invalid input
value:1234567890
>>>
```

Is it my (return -1) are not in the right place. Help please.Thanks

Comment: get your input at the beginning of every loop. Then remove the return

Answer (score 0):

```
def getValidNumber():
    while True:
        number = input('value:')
        if number.isdigit() and (len(number) == 10):
            return number
        elif (len(number) != 10):
            print('invalid input')

number = getValidNumber()
```

Comment: how to make If the number is missing or invalid, return ‐1 to the calling procedure?. That's is the requirement needed. Any suggestion for my program?

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle that situation.  If you just return -1, then you have to check for that, i.e. if number < 0....

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: You could throw an exception.  You could retry.  It depends on how this function fits into your larger program.